# How to pass a string or two strings into a partial view from the page not using a model on the razor page?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor-pages, partial-views

I have a simple callout partial included in this way I would like to implement or very close to it.

```
<partial name="_Callout" model='"Aviso:Todos..."' />
```

In the partial view I have this simple code (will make more complex later)

```
<div class="callout callout-info"><strong>Aviso</strong>Todos...</div>
```

I thought in the partial I will split the string and place the s[0] into the strong and s[1] into the div.

There has to be a simple way to pass a string, can probably do a new string[] {"",""} but not sure this is the correct method of passing data into a partial view.

Comment: You explicitly say "not using a model" - why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you pass a string to partial view,and you split the data with ":",here is a demo to place the s[0] into the strong and s1 into the div:

```
<partial name="_Callout" model='"Aviso:Todos...:B:b:C:c"' />
```

partial view:

```
@model string
@{
    string[] ls = Model.Split(":");
}
@for (var i = 0; i < ls.Length; i=i+2)
{
<div class="callout callout-info">

    <strong>@ls[i]</strong>
    @if (i + 1 < ls.Length)
    {
        @ls[i + 1]
    }
</div>
}
```

result:

[image]

Comment: was so close, that is what I was doing except @model sting.    Thanks